# PHP errors / exceptions in loop prevent further iterations

Tags: php, observer-pattern

In my PHP project,Observer Pattern used everywhere,like:

```
foreach ($this->_aObserver as $observer)
{
    $observer->vOnUpdate();
}
```

But if one observer shutdown because of **Fatal Error** or **Uncaught Exception**, the rest of observers **can not** be triggered.

So any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Not much you're going to be able to do about _"Fatal Error"_

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're implementing the observer pattern yourself and by observer shutting down you mean an exception is thrown you can wrap the method call in a `try...catch`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
foreach ($this->_aObserver as $observer)
{
    try {
        $observer->vOnUpdate();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        // do something with the error or just move on?
    }
}
```

For the fatal error catching you'll have to create a function to catch the fatal error and basically ignore it. Which this isn't recommended, fatal errors are not meant to be recovered from. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: en...if one observer shutdown beacause of Fatal Error or Uncaught Exception，it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try catch

```
foreach ($this->_aObserver as $observer)
{
    try {
        $observer->vOnUpdate();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
      //  log message
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the method exists and then call itif yes.

```
foreach ($this->_aObserver as $observer)
{
  try {
    if (method_exists($observer, 'vOnUpdate')) {
      $observer->vOnUpdate();
    }
  } catch(\Exception $e) {
    // echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage();
  }
}
```